# execute shell script from a php

Tags: php, shell, ssh

I'm trying to get some commands executed on a distant device. I'm using public and private key to connect to distant device.

In my server i have just to type : ssh username@distant_device command and i get the result of it. So i want to do this throught a php page.

I tried different methods and it didn't work for me.

1 -

```
 $cmdline = escapeshellcmd("ssh username@distant_device command");
 system($cmdline);
```

2 - executing shell script in the server

script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(ssh username@distant_device command)
echo "$output" >> test.txt

exit 0
```

php code :

```
passthru('./script.sh',$result);
echo $result ;
```

I got result sending by my script but not the result of the ssh command in it. When i execute the script directly i have the result.

3-

```
system ("ssh username@distant_device command > test.txt");
system ("ssh -i /home/nagios/.ssh/id_rsa -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' username@distant_device command' > test.txt");
```

text file remain empty

What i'am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, here it is :

```
$host = "ip_address"; 
$port = 22; 
$conn = ssh2_connect($host, $port); 
$username = "username"; 
$pub_key = "/path/to/key/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"; 
$pri_key = "/path/to/key/.ssh/id_rsa"; 
if(ssh2_auth_pubkey_file( 
    $conn, 
    $username, 
    $pub_key, 
    $pri_key)) 
{ 
    echo "Authentication succeeded";
    $stdout_stream = ssh2_exec($conn, 'ping ip_address rapid routing-instance XXXXXXXXX');
    sleep(1);
    stream_set_blocking($stdout_stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stdout_stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
    echo '</pre>';

} 
else 
{ 
   echo "Authentication failed "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec()` for example

```
$output = shell_exec('./deploy.sh');
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Php has a good documentation on it http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php
hope it helps :)

Comment: i got the same empty result :(